# Using JavaScript to connect to a .NET server

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services

I'm supposed to reach a resource using JS from our server. I've set up the code below.

```
var targetUrl = "http://somePlace.com/actualResourceName";
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.onload = function () { alert(xdr.responseText); }
xdr.open("GET", targetUrl);
xdr.send();
```

However, I'm not clear how the method on the other side needs to be created. I've come up with the following suggestion, fully aware that it's not working. I'm sure I'm missing the right attributes, for instance. I'm not even sure where to set that the method is supposed to react on `actualResourceName`...

```
[???]
public String ActualResourceName()
{
  return "Bye, bye, cruel word!";
}
```

I've googled around but I haven't found any solution. I might have stumbled across it without realizing that it's something useful, though.

How should the method in C# be written?

Comment: I assume it's going to be a REST-service, written in C#. What type of service is used here? ASP.NET WebApi? Service Stack? Or maybe even ASP.NET MVC? If none of the above, you're in for reinventing the weel and pain that goes with it... :)

Comment: You will probably want to create a WCF service that will sit on the server side and respond to requests from your client side javascript. If nobody gives you a decent answer I'll try posting a full code example later this evening if I have time. The following link gives you a step-by-step walk-through and is well worth reading (it is a bit long) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

Comment: I would recommend using ASP.NET Web API for an easy to develop REST API that can be called from JavaScript/JQuery.  ASP.NET Web API is a joint effort by the ASP.NET and WCF teams and is the future direction for RESTful web services. A complete tutorial on how to create the web service and the JavaScript to call it can be found here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here it goes. I'll describe two ways to get it done, easiest ones:

[**1. ASP.NET WebApi**](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

You'll have to create a new ASP.NET MVC4 project (be it release or RC), select the 'WebApi' as an option:
[image: Project startup]

And you'll have the template ready. Now you right click 'Controllers' folder, then 
Add -> Controller:
[image]

and fill it out e.g. like that:

```
public class ActualResourceController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hey there! Getting the resource...";
    }
}
```

Default routes are in Global.asax, when you go to definition of `WebApiConfig.Register(...)` method, you'll see that the default route is `host/api/controller`.
Let's try that out, when you start up the project and go under (in my case, the port is chosen automatically by the development server) `http://localhost:23030/api/ActualResource`
you'll get:

```xml
<string>Hey there! Getting the resource...</string>
```

WebApi returns either JSON or XML depending on the `Accept` header, if you want JSON to be the only one/default, take [a look at this link.](http://ellisweb.net/2012/04/force-webapi-to-return-json-by-default-for-html-get-requests/)

You can of course create a class and return it, it will get serialized to XML/JSON in a similar fashion you'll see below with ServiceStack.

---

[**2. ServiceStack**](http://www.servicestack.net/)

Now the ServiceStack is powerful, open-source REST web-service framework. It works a little bit different than WebApi, and here's a quick introduction (although the documentation is good):

Create the regular ASP.NET MVC project (in my case, MVC4) - you'll have an empty template:

[image: service stack startup project]

Then fire up the Package Manager Console and type (like the documentation suggests) `Install-Package ServiceStack.Host.Mvc`, which will get you a ServiceStack project template with a tutorial app and such which you can later on remove if you wish.

But first things first, the ServiceStack works on DTOs, the Request-Response objects. So let's create them, the `ActualResource` class which will serve as a request and `ActualResourceResponse` which will be a response. Since you have no parameters in a request, the first one is trivial:

```
public class ActualResource
{
}
```

Any parameters would be automatic properties. Now the response:

```
public class ActualResourceResponse
{
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
}
```

And the service class itself:

```
public class ActualResourceService : Service
{
    public object Get(ActualResource request)
    {
        return new ActualResourceResponse {
           ResourceName = "Hi! It's the resource name." };
    }
}
```

You could of course return bare `string` for your current purposes, it would work all the same.

Now in the template ServiceStack creates, everything happens in AppHost.cs file, let's take a look and modify it a tiny little bit:

```
Routes
    .Add<Hello>("/hello") 
    .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name*}")
    .Add<Todo>("/todos")
    .Add<Todo>("/todos/{Id}") //everything up to here are a template/tutorial routes, you can safely remove them
    .Add<ActualResource>("/actualResource"); //and here you add a route to your own service
```

For it to work, you have to go to Global.asax and comment out the whole `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)` line, then go into the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` method and add:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}"); // <<<---- this line
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

A little more plumbing is required, but it's still not bad.

Now when you start the service, go under `localhost:whateverport/api/actualResource`, you'll get the familiar string, and here's a screenshot:
[image: ServiceStack reply page]

ServiceStack can serialize to various formats, so if you go under `http://localhost:yourPort/api/actualResource?format=json`, you'll get:

```
{"resourceName":"Hi! It's the resource name."}
```

if `?format=xml`, then:

```xml
<ActualResourceResponse>
    <ResourceName>Hi! It's the resource name.</ResourceName>   
</ActualResourceResponse>
```

And so on...

Now the ServiceStack setup is a bit more complicated, but it supports e.g. Memcache out of the box, you can plumb in Redis, you can use various authentication providers, all of that may be quite useful in some scenarios. But, as Uncle Ben once said, "with great power comes great responsibility", and a bit harder setup phase...

---

Now you can choose whichever you feel like, these two are the simplest options right now IMHO. Of course it's only a simple tutorial to get you started, you'll have a chance to explore this topic in depth when you get going with the project.

Comment: Curious why you think ServiceStack is more complicated to setup? It's 1-line to register your choice of Memcached or Redis `ICacheClient`'s, etc and Each Auth Provider registration is a single line of config.

Comment: @mythz A bit more complicated than the *completely* ready, out of the box WebApi, but (maybe) due to that more customizable. But don't get me wrong, I use ServiceStack and I very much like it - although you could use a little documentation update to MVC 4 - e.g. you have to comment-out the API route registration completely for it to work - or maybe alter it to different routes, I'm not quite sure, I didn't really go into it. It's a minor detail, I know, but it still has to be done. :) And thanks for the correction on new API.

Comment: How can WebApi be *Completely ready*? What does it take to use Redis or Memcached? and I can't imagine different Auth Providers can just work out-of-the-box either? I'll look into MVC4, might need a wiki docs/NuGet update.

Comment: @mythz You create the project and it *just* works, no alterations needed - that's what I meant. Not much of a customization either. So maybe it could be easier to pick up at the first glance, but ServiceStack very much makes sense when you go through the docs and have the starter template. Although I have to say the documentation got me a little bit confused at first with service with attributes (`[Route=]`), RestServiceBase and now the new API, but everything else was really simple to implement. :) I'll have to catch up with the changes...

Comment: ok cool so you mean using the VS.NET project template just works? not that the caching + auth providers are ready to go out-of-the-box? This is something we'll be improving when we ship VS.NET support next year.

Comment: @mythz Exactly that. Good to know it will be improved, especially since it's not bad right now. :)